# API calls from JavaScript to backend: Ensuring legitimacy without server-side code

Tags: javascript, api, security, widget

I want to create a Javascript widget that my users can put on their websites.
The widget is capable of creating audio, **which in turn costs my users' money.**

For the sake of illustration, let's say that every time a widget, placed on my user's site, is loaded by anyone on the internet (i.e. my users' users), I bill my user $1.

The widget is a Javascript code wrapped around an HTML audio player. The JS code makes a request to my backend API every time it is loaded, and upon receiving the response from my backend API, the player is constructed.

Diagram:

[image: diagram]

**My concern is** malicious usage by people who are not my users.
Let's say someone takes the widget's source code they found on a website that belongs to one of my users, and they put it on *their* site. They will, therefore, use my service but not pay for it. Instead, my actual user will pay for it (assuming I use a public API key as a way of distinguishing my users).

Usually, this is prevented by having a server-side library be responsible for any usages that might spend money. For example, I use Pusher as my WebSockets IaaS, and whenever I want to publish messages, I have to do it server-side, using their PHP SDK, with both private and public API keys.

In my use case, it's mandatory not to have a server-side library.

**Question: how do I make sure that API requests I receive are legitimate?**

I considered using the hostname where the widget is placed as a legitimacy measure. During the widget set-up, I could ask my users to whitelist certain (sub)domains and reject all requests that don't match the criteria, but this could be easily spoofed by, for example, a custom local domain or a CURL-crafted request.

I understand this may not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you're asking is closely related to the topic of client side encryption. In most cases, the answer would be no, its not possible. However, in this case, it may be possible to implement something along the lines of the following. If you can get your clients to install a plugin (which you would build), you could encrypt your JS code after finishing it, and have your server serve this encrypted file. Normally, where this falls short, is that if you're sending an encrypted file, there needs to be a way for the client to decrypt it. This would require you to also serve an unecrypted JS file which would do the decoding, but by serving the unencrypted decoder you undo any security gained by encrypting your main JS file (the decryption file could be easily used to reverse engineer your encryption method/ just straight up run for people other than your intended users). Now, this is where having those API users (and the ability to communicate with them through means outside of server-client connections) comes in handy. If you build a decryption plugin, and give it to the API users (you could issue a unique decryption key for each user, but without server access implementing unique user keys would be very difficult/impossible), the plugin could then decrypt your served file in their browser, essentially guaranteeing that only users you have given the 'key' to can access your software. However, this approach has a few caveats. It implies that you trust your users enough that they wouldn't distribute the plugin (it would be against their intrest to distribute it anyway, as it could lead to higher chargers if people impersonate them). There are also probably a couple of other security concerns with this approach, however, I can't think of them right now. If any come to mind, I'll edit this post and add them.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I have come up with something today on my own today, too, so I'm gonna be posting it as an answer later today, and hopefully, you can weigh in with your opinion.

Comment: Yeah, I'm curious to see what you have in mind, ill leave my thoughts when you post your idea!

Comment: I've just posted it. Feel free to review it.

Answer (score 1):

apparently, I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, hence the post...
But in response to your post, I think that method seems much better than the one I suggested; I didn't realize you could control the API's response to the server.

I don't quite understand which of the following you mean:

a) Send a JS file to the user, with the sole purpose of determining if the player should also be sent (ie upon arriving, it pings the server with the client's API key/ url) and *then* the server would serve the file (in which case your approach seems safe to me, but others may find security problems with it).

or

b) Send a file with the JS *and* the audio player, which upon arriving, determines if the URL and API key are correct, and then allows the audio player to function normally (sending the API key to the server to track usage, not as a security feature).

If using option b, this would not improve security. If your code relies on security that runs on the client-side, and the security system was sent by the same means as the code, then almost without exception, the system designed is flawed and inherently unsafe.

I hope this makes helps, and if you disagree / have more questions, feel free to comment!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I meant a). So yes, have JS send parameters to the API backend with target URL (which is the current URL where the widget was loaded), and let the backend determine whether or not the request should be fulfilled based on the intersection of target URL and whitelisted (sub)domains. TLDR let the server validate the request, not the frontend, is the takeaway from this. Should have thought of it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

How about sending the following parameters from JavaScript widget to API backend:

- Public API key (e.g. `bbbe3b259f881cfc796f468619eb9d`)
- Current URL (e.g. `https://example.com/articles/chiang-mai-thailand-january-2016-june-2016`)

I will use the API key as a way of distinguishing *my* user and the current URL as a way of knowing which audio file to create (my widget will create an audio file based on the URL).

Furthermore, **and this is crucial**, I will have a user whitelist their domains and subdomains on my central site, where my users will get their widget code.

This is the same as what FB does for their integrations:
[image]

So if for example, my backend API receives the aforementioned sample URL, and the user has set up the widget to only allow URLs that belong to `foo.com` and `bar.baz.com`, I will reject the audio creation process and display an error.

Do you see any issues with this approach?

Comment: @Arthur-R what do you think?